# Javascript Runtime Error in VS2012

Tags: javascript, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-runtime

I face a problem to compile windows 8 application which is create using visual studio 2012 windows runtime component project. I'm using html 5 , javascript and c++ to develop this application. But when I compile the project I'm getting error which is JavaScript runtime error: Error in the DLL.

I don't know how to fixed this problem and when i build this project I'm getting error like below:-

```
Error   40  Loading assembly "D:\workspace\Test\apps\Test\windows8\native\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1\WindowsRuntimeComponent1.dll" failed. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsRuntimeComponent1.dll' or one of its dependencies. This operation is only valid in the context of an application container. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007109A)
File name: 'WindowsRuntimeComponent1.dll'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ReadAssemblyResources(String name)
    C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets 383 9   Test
```

May I ask how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: This does not look like **javascript** runtime error at all.

Comment: Are you creating a windows store app or a component? Looks to me like a component, and then my question is can you provide more information of the structure of the project(s) and the referenced assemblies? 
Also, do you get warnings and other errors?
Are you using third party libraries?

Comment: Can this be the problem:  "D:\workspace\...."? Are you by any chance trying to *run* the application on an external drive? Just checking :)

Comment: Yes. I'm create a windows runtime component and I'm also getting a warning such as '<':signed/unsigned mismatch. I'm create an application about read data from database which is include sqlite3.dll  . But now I'm facing problem when compiling the project and it is write at above. So, what should I do to solve this problem

Comment: Are you adding sqlite to the component? WinRT components have restrictions that will cause problems with the sqlite library. If so remove it to see if that is the problem. If it is then it means you know where to start looking.
The <':signed/unsigned I'm not a C++ programmer but signed means the value can be negative, while the unsigned means it cannot be. Compiler warns you that there is a mismatch that can cause problems later http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/750/. You can either 1) change the code 2)ignore the warning 3)turn of the warning (not what I would recommend)